# Different behaviour of axes object?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Maybe I am being extremely slow today, but I swear this has worked for me before and was showing a plot, now it returns a list with a single `Lines` object:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(values)
```

And I get `<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f04a33d6cc0>` instead of a plot...

However, if I use this `%matplotlib nbagg` and do the same it works. I then stop the interaction and I get my desired result. What is going on here?

My versions:

python 3.6.5

matplotlib 2.2.2

jupyter 4.4.0

ipython 6.4.0

ipywidgets 7.2.1

Thanks

Comment: if you call `f` then you can see the plot...

Comment: Is the complete code in one cell of the notebook?

Comment: no. `%matplotlib inline` and `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` are in one cell, and then everything else is in a different.

Comment: I guess that should work. [This is what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9CKK.png). Did you restart the kernel? (Maybe something just went wrong previously such that no plots are shown.) You should btw. be able to call `plt.show()` in the same cell the figure is created in case it is not shown automatically.

Comment: Hmm.. I restarted the kernel a couple of times. Same behaviour. Strange

Comment: So I think the behaviour you're seeing is expected if you don't use `%matplotlib inline`, i.e. run a notebook without this command. But since you are using it... When you say it has worked before, is there anything you did in between?

Comment: Nope. Not using inline and using plt.show() also does not work :) haha

Comment: tried on a laptop now. Same behaviour

Comment: I'm out of ideas. But you may want to state all versions in use, Ipython, jupyter, matplotlib, additional packages like ipywidgets etc. Maybe someone has an idea based on that.